# Bluehost Too Many Connections Error Although There is No Traffic

Tags: mysql, wordpress

We have a Wordpress website in development stage hosted on Bluehost shared hosting. Although there is no traffic, I get this error:

```
    Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): (08004/1040): Too many connections in /wp-includes/class-wpdb.php on line 1775

Too many connections
```

This happens randomly. And I use global $wpdb for every database queries I make. According to https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/117495/database-connection-close wpdb class automatically closes the connection. So we should have only one or two active connections as the site is not accessible by public.

wp-config.php file content

```
define('DB_NAME', 'example');
define('DB_USER', 'example');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'example');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define( 'DB_CHARSET', 'utf8' );
define( 'DB_COLLATE', '' );

define('AUTH_KEY', 'example');
define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY', 'example');
define('LOGGED_IN_KEY', 'example');
define('NONCE_KEY', 'example');
define('AUTH_SALT', 'example');
define('SECURE_AUTH_SALT', 'example');
define('LOGGED_IN_SALT', 'example');
define('NONCE_SALT', 'example');

$table_prefix = '8zW_';
define('WP_CRON_LOCK_TIMEOUT', 120);
define('AUTOSAVE_INTERVAL', 300);
define('WP_POST_REVISIONS', 5);
define('EMPTY_TRASH_DAYS', 7);
define('WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE', true);

define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    define( 'ABSPATH', __DIR__ . '/' );
}
require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php';
```

Comment: Disable persistent connections.

Comment: I get empty value for echo ini_get('mysql.allow_persistent'); and if I try to use ini_set('mysql.allow_persistent','0'); it still returns empty.

Comment: Did you mean to use `mysqli.allow_persistent`?

Comment: Yes I tried to set/get mysqli.allow_persistent through php as I dont have access to mysql server configuration.

Comment: I am confused. Why would you need access to MySQL server? Anyway, if you are using WordPress then it means you MUST have access to MySQL server, so what do you mean you have no access? Also, you should be changing WP environment values, not PHP INI values.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Bluehost has multiple customers sharing each MySQL server. It is possible some other customer's code uses up the server's connection pool. If, and only if, your WordPress installation is generic (without exotic plugins) ask their support team to move your account to a different server. Their private-equity owners are squeezing resources.

Comment: @Dharman I can't set mysql settings via mysql connection as I'm not allowed to do so.

Comment: I'm sorry but I still do not understand what you are talking about. Please [edit] the question to provide more details. Show us the WordPress config file. If the error is not coming from standard WP installation then show us the code that generated this error.

Comment: @Dharman What do you mean by "Disable persistent connections." One way is using PHP to set mysqli.allow_persistent and another one is mysql server configuration. Can you tell what should I do to "Disable persistent connections" ?

Comment: This should help https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/31018#:~:text=WordPress%20currently%20does%20not%20allow,php%20file.

Comment: @Dharman I added wp-config file content.